# Looping through multiple CSV-files in different folders and producing multiple outputs and put these in the same folder based on input

Tags: python, loops, directory

Problem: I have around 100 folders in 1 main folder each with a csv file with the exact same name and structure, for example input.csv. I have written a Python script for one of the files which takes the csv-file as an input and gives two images as output in the same folder. I want to produce these images and put them in every folder given the input per folder.

Is there a fast way to do this? Until now I have copied my script every time in each folder and been executing it. For 5 folders it was alright, but for 100 this will get tedious and take a lot of time.

Can someone please help met out? I'm very new to coding w.r.t. directories, paths, files etc. I have already tried to look for a solution, but no succes so far.

Comment: Use `pathlib` and `rglob`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path = r'path\to\folders'
filename = 'input'

# get all directories within the top level directory 
dirs = [os.path.join(path, val) for val in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, val))]

# loop through each directory 
for dd in dirs:
    file_ = [f for f in os.listdir(dd) if f.endwith('.csv') and 'input' in f]
    if file_:
        # this assumes only a single file of 'filename' and extension .csv exists in each directory 
        file_ = file_[0]
    else:
        continue
    data = pd.read_csv(file_)

    # apply your script here and save images back to folder dd
```